# Sass mixins that are the same with different image file locations

Tags: sass, mixins

I have these 2 mixins, the only difference is the image file location. Is there a cleaner and better way of doing this? I would like to be able to just include the mixin I need without having to override the file location in my .scss file.

```
  @mixin retinize($file, $type, $width, $height) {
      background-image: url('../img/' + $file + '.' + $type);

      @media #{$is-hidpi} {
        & {
          background-image: url('../img/' + $file + '-ret.' + $type);
          -webkit-background-size: $width $height;
             -moz-background-size: $width $height;
                  background-size: $width $height;
        }
      }
    }

    @mixin retinize-docroot($file, $type, $width, $height) {
      background-image: url('/DocRoot/1/Img/' + $file + '.' + $type);

      @media #{$is-hidpi} {
        & {
          background-image: url('/DocRoot/1/Img/' + $file + '-ret.' + $type);
          -webkit-background-size: $width $height;
             -moz-background-size: $width $height;
                  background-size: $width $height;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snugug you were right on, but I had the change `$url` by removing the `'.'` and adding it to the next line for `$low`. Your way was adding an extra `.` to the retina image. Thanks so much for your help.

```
@mixin retinize($file, $type, $width, $height, $docroot: false) {
  $url: if($docroot == false, '../img/', '/DocRoot/1/Img/');
  $url: $url + $file;
  $low: $url + '.' + $type;
  $high: $url + '-ret.' + $type;

  background-image: url('#{$low}');

  @media #{$is-hidpi} {
    background-image: url('#{$high}');
    -webkit-background-size: $width $height;
    -moz-background-size: $width $height;
    background-size: $width $height;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd do something like the following:

```
@mixin retinize($file, $type, $width, $height, $docroot: false) {
  $url: if($docroot == false, '../img/', '/DocRoot/1/Img/');
  $url: $url + $file + '.';
  $low: $url + $type;
  $high: $url + '-ret.' + type;

  background-image: url('#{$low}');

  @media #{$is-hidpi} {
    background-image: url('#{$high}');
    -webkit-background-size: $width $height;
    -moz-background-size: $width $height;
    background-size: $width $height;
  }
}
```

What I'm doing here is I'm adding a new argument to pass to tell if the image is at docroot and using the inline `if` function to write the correct prefix. I then build the rest of the shared URL and create low/high variables. Finally, I include the media query. I don't include the nested `&` as media queries bubble out and wrap the selector they're in; if you need it for the doubling of the selector, feel free to add it back in. I'd also recommend removing the `-moz` prefix as it hasn't been needed since Firefox 3.6 and the `-webkit` prefix unless you need first class support for Android 2.3 (check [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts) for browser support)

Comment: According to Google, 40% of Android users are running 2.3.